# "Invalid argument" when using 3 part open in perl

Tags: perl, encoding

I'm extremely new to perl (and programming, for that matter) so I'm sorry if this is just a stupid mistake.

I'm trying to write a script that pulls a list of files from a .txt file, opens each one, looks for lines that match some regex, and prints those lines to a new file in a structure that will make a valid .csv file (using the capture groups in the regex).

My script works for English UTF-8 files, but when it tries to process non-English files the text data appears with spaces between each letter and the regex doesn't match - I'm guessing this is because they're saved in UTF-16. My thinking was to make the open command three parts, so that it also uses the ":encoding(UTF-16)" parameter for non-English files, but that's resulted in an invalid argument error. In fact, I can't get the script to run at all without using a two-part open command.

Here's my script.

```
use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Slurp;

my @intfilelist = read_file('filelist_int.txt');

unlink "int_temp.csv";

foreach my $intfile (@intfilelist) {
    open (my $file, "<:encoding(UTF-16)", $intfile) or die "Whoops! $!";
    while (my $line = <$file>) {
        if ($line =~ m/^(\d{3,5})\t(.*)$/) {
            chomp $line;
            open (my $csv, ">>", "int_temp.csv");
            print $csv ("\"$intfile\",\"$1\",\"$2\"\n");
            close $csv;
        }
    }
}
```

Changing `open (my $file, "<:encoding(UTF-16)", $intfile)` to `open (my $file, $intfile)` causes the script to work, except for the aforementioned issues with non-English files.

Like I said, I've only been playing with perl for 2 days, so sorry if I've misused some terminology or overlooked something obvious. Appreciate any help!

Comment: i doubt `open $file, $intfile` works. Try to add $intfile to your die-message so you can have a look wether its a valid filename.

Comment: `open $a,$b` is shorthand for `open $a, '<', $b`

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. I meant `open (my $file, $intfile)`. I fixed it in the original post. Adding $intfile to my die message just displayed the first entry in filelist_int.txt.

Comment: i see. is it possible that utf-16 encoding is not available for some reason?

Comment: What version of Perl are you running? (`perl -v`)

Comment: @marderh You would know better than I do. The files I'm reading from are just text files with arbitrary extensions.

Comment: @Borodin perl 5, version 14, subversion 2. I think I picked up "use 5.010" from a tutorial somewhere (I don't honestly remember) - should that match my perl version?

Comment: @nkaun: No that's fine. `use 5.010` requires only that you are running on version 10 or later.

Comment: not sure if thats really the problem, but `read_file` sucks the line breaks too. Can you try a `chomp $intfile;` before the `open`?

Comment: @marderh That did it! I'm not totally sure what I did, but it works and that's all I really care about for now. :) Thanks!

Comment: I'd just like to add: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great that you're using Perl, and this is a really good first question, even though you figured it out from comments. Keep this up! :)

Comment: @nkaun you're welcome. I hope you'll enjoy Perl in the future!

Answer (score 9):

Remove the newline at the end of the filenames that you read from the first file with `File::Slurp`. You can do this with `chomp $intfile;` right before the `open`.

`chomp` (see [Perldoc Chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)) removes newlines from the end of a given string.

Comment: I found the same thing. Use chomp to strip the EOL on each $intfile